# Jasmine & Karma : 'mat-chip-list' is not a known element while testing Angular

Tags: html, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I have this error showing up when i try to run tests with Jasmine and Karma :

```
'mat-chip-list' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-chip-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-chip-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("iv class="tag">IAM</div>
    <mat-form-field class="chips" (focusout)="saveFormValue('iam')">
      [ERROR ->]<mat-chip-list #chipListIAM class="field">
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let iam of iams"
               "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/Component.html@33:6
```

The problem is when i run my Angular code, i don't have such problem everything run correctly since i declared my element in AppModule so i don't know why while testing i have this error.

Here is My HTML code :

```
  <div class="left-side">
    <mat-form-field class="chips" (focusout)="saveFormValue('groups')">
      <mat-chip-list #chipListGroup class="field">
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let group of groups"
                  [selectable]="selectable"
                  [removable]="removable"
                  [color]="primary"
                  selected
                  (removed)="onRemoveGroup(group)">
          {{group.name}}
          <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
      </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

And here is my AppModule :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [Component, DetailsComponent],
  exports: [
    Component
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    FormsModule
  ]
})
```

And here is my testing file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { FormRoutesDetailsComponent } from './details.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

describe('DetailsComponent', () => {
  let component: DetailsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DetailsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DetailsComponent ],
      imports: [
        FormsModule
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the MatChipsModule (and every other Module used by the component to be tested) in your TestingModule aswell.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ DetailsComponent ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    MatChipsModule
  ]
})
```